# How to get rid of a sub query?

Tags: sql, axapta

Is it possible in this request to get rid of the sub query, maybe replacing with join notexist?

Query is necessary for Axapta.

```
select count(*)
from rec join (
  select max(`date`) d, id 
  from rec
  where 
    `date`<"2013-05-03 00:00:00"
  group by id
) drec on rec.id = drec.id and rec.`date` = drec.d
where 
  rec.value>0;
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Can you please rephrase your question? Thanks.

Comment: To better serve you, use your exact SQL statement with the proper table names.

Comment: Also spell out what your intended output should be.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the sub query?

Comment: I want to change, because there is no x ++ design subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find the number of records for the max `date` for each `id`? In this case something similar to the code below might work in AX. I haven't tested it since you hadn't provided the table names, etc., so some adjustments might be required:

```
YourTable rec;
YourTable rec2;

while select date, id, count(RecId) from rec
group by date, id
    where rec.value > 0
       && rec.date  < 03\05\2013
notexists join rec2
    where rec2.id == rec.id
       && rec2.date > rec.date 
       && rec2.date < 03\05\2013
{
    info(strFmt('Id = %1, date = %2, number of records = %3', rec.id, rec.date, rec.RecId));
}
```